# Linking Keys with loops? C#

Tags: c#, console-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GameEdition3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Data classData = new Data();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.TitleMenu());

        while (true) 
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo PressKey;
            PressKey = Console.ReadKey();

            while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.TitleMenu());
                PressKey  = Console.ReadKey();
            }



            while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.I)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.Information());
                PressKey =Console.ReadKey();
            }

            while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Please type in the Item you want. Warhammer, Heavy Armor, Boots, or Sword: ");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.myFunction());
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Backspace to go back to the menu and you can view your item in the Display all Items tab");
                PressKey = Console.ReadKey();
            }

            while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.result);
                PressKey = Console.ReadKey();


            }

            while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                PressKey = Console.ReadKey();

            }


            if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
            {
                return;

            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }


    }
}
```

**/

Hello. I made this noob game where you press a key to get a different menu and set of directions up. The problem is, once I press a key and go to that specific method, I can't go back. I would like PressedKey to keep looping so I can press keys to go to the different parts of the program. I hope I explained this good enough.

Example: I press the key I. Key I goes to the set of directions. I need to hit backspace to go to the Main menu. Backspace doesn't work. How do I make these ConsoleKeys to work?

PS: I tried while, if statements, do while, and while(true).

Here is the class that comes with it if someone wants to try it out: 
http://pastebin.com/GivANrwC
Name the class Data.cs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is the line `Console.Read();` at the end of the loop. This tells the program to wait for a line of text to be entered, followed by the Enter key. The first letter of the text that was typed is not saved anywhere and is *lost*.

After removing that line, you still call `Console.ReadKey()` too much. Each time you call that method, it eats the key that is typed. So if, for example, you press 'I', then you enter this section:

```
    while (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.I)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.Information());
        PressKey =Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

After the `WriteLine`, it calls `ReadKey()`, and if it's not `ConsoleKey.I`, it exits the small loop and then restarts the bigger loop. But at the beginning of the bigger loop, you call `ReadKey()` again, without ever checking the value of the last key pressed.

Try this version instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GameEdition3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Data classData = new Data();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.TitleMenu());

        while (true) 
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo PressKey;
            PressKey = Console.ReadKey();

            if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.TitleMenu());
            }
            else if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.I)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.Information());
            }
            else if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Please type in the Item you want. Warhammer, Heavy Armor, Boots, or Sword: ");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.myFunction());
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress Backspace to go back to the menu and you can view your item in the Display all Items tab");
            }
            else if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", classData.result);
            }
            else if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
            else if (PressKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

This also shows that there's no need to use small `while` loops when you're checking which key was pressed. Let all the looping be done by the outer loop.

Comment: WOW AMAZING! I would've never figured that out. I always thought you needed the Console.Read(); at the end. Now I know better. You explained it so a noob like me could understand.